# Unit testing framework for a Swing UI

Tags: java, unit-testing, swing

Testing UI is difficult. What do you think is the best unit testing framework for Swing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently the best in my opinion is [FEST](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Home).

Comment: FEST is now AssertJ-Swing

Answer (score 7):

> What do you think is the best unit
>   testing framework for Swing?

Good question. I can't help you with that. I can point you to articles about ui testing I have read from [Misko Hevery's](http://misko.hevery.com/) site

### Misko Hevery's tips

- I would like to point you out to
  Google's testing guru Misko Hevery's
  website. He talks a lot about how to
  write code that is easy to test.
- For example When reading his excellent slides ["How to Write Hard to Test
  Code"](https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B7z6S2TvsDWSYWQ1NGEwOTctYTEwOS00ZTUwLWE2Y2QtZjEwMmE2OTQzNjVh&hl=en) he points out at
  slides 45/288 that the cost of
  fixing rendering bugs is relatively
  low. I think that he is right about that
  and that you should not be to
  concerned with having 100% code
  coverage off your UI.
- He also has some good tips to over how to test your [UI](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/05/testing-ui-part1/).

  > The important thing is to separate the
  >   graphical UI from the control logic
  >   and data. This can be achieved with
  >   the standard Model View Controller
  >   design pattern

### ObjectMentor

This is a website about testing.I found this interesting article from Michael Featers explaining [UI Test Automation Tools are Snake Oil](http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2010/01/04/ui-test-automation-tools-are-snake-oil)

Answer (score 5):

I have been using [Jemmy](https://jemmy.dev.java.net/) on top of JUnit. You can see a snippet of their example [test-case actions](https://jemmy.dev.java.net/samples/ActionsSample.java) here:

```
    new ClassReference("org.netbeans.jemmy.explorer.GUIBrowser")
        .startApplication();
    JFrameOperator mainFrame = new JFrameOperator("GUI Browser");

    new JButtonOperator(mainFrame, "Reload In").push();
    new JLabelOperator(mainFrame, "Reloaded");

    JTreeOperator tree = new JTreeOperator(mainFrame);

    //click in the middle of the tree
    tree.clickMouse();

    //collapse node     
    tree.collapsePath(tree.findPath("", "|"));

    //expand node       
    tree.expandPath(tree.findPath("", "|"));

    //select node
    tree.selectPath(tree.findPath("GUI Browser", "|"));

    JTextFieldOperator testField = new JTextFieldOperator(mainFrame);

    //type new value in the text field
    testField.clearText();
    testField.typeText("3");
```