# Testing drag-and-drop files onto application

Tags: java, swing, junit, drag-and-drop, junit4

I am looking for a method to perform a drag-and-drop of a file/multiple files onto my application from a unit test. For example selecting some files in Windows Explorer, drag them and drop them on my application.

I am capable of testing drag-and-drop behavior between two components in my application (see below - feel free to indicate if you know a better way), but I have no idea how to do the same when the data has to come from outside my application.

I thought about using the debugger to inspect a 'file' `Transferable` when I do the drag-and-drop operation by hand, but there must be a better way then hard-coding a complete `Transferable`.

Example of a drag-and-drop test between components

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class DragAndDropTest {
  @Test
  public void dragAndDropBetweenTwoTextFields() {
    JTextField firstField = new JTextField();
    JTextField secondField = new JTextField();
    String testText = "Test text";
    firstField.setText( testText );
    firstField.selectAll();
    Action copyAction = TransferHandler.getCopyAction();
    copyAction.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( firstField, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Copy" ) );
    Action pasteAction = TransferHandler.getPasteAction();
    pasteAction.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( secondField, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Paste" ) );
    assertEquals( "Text is not copied", testText, secondField.getText() );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Based on the comments under this question, I have updated my code snippet to 'fake' a drag-and-drop by providing a hard-coded `Transferable`. The code also  contains a little main program which just creates an empty frame on which you can drop files. The path will then be printed on the console.

On my PC, drag-and-drop of a file does not use the `javaFileListFlavor` but the URI flavor. 
Previous experiences (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700073/drag-and-drop-differences-between-jdk1-6-and-jdk1-7)) already teached me that the `Transferable` a component receives when dragging something from outside the Java application might differ in subtle ways.

So to be completely clear: I want to test the part of my code that extracts the information from the received `Transferable`. The 'information-handling' code (e.g. what happens when the application receives the file) can easily be tested without bothering with D&D. I just need to make sure I extract the correct information from the `Transferable`, and it is silly to test this with a hard-coded `Transferable`.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class DragAndDropTest {
  private static DataFlavor URI_LIST_FLAVOR = null;
  static {
    try {
      URI_LIST_FLAVOR = new DataFlavor( "text/uri-list;class=java.lang.String" );
    }
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException ignore ) {
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testFileDragAndDrop() throws IOException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
    JComponent testComponent = new JPanel();
    TestingTransferHandler transferHandler = new TestingTransferHandler();
    testComponent.setTransferHandler( transferHandler );
    Clipboard clipBoard = new JLabel(  ).getToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable transferable = new Transferable() {
      @Override
      public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return new DataFlavor[]{URI_LIST_FLAVOR};
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor flavor ) {
        return flavor == URI_LIST_FLAVOR;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getTransferData( DataFlavor flavor ) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if ( flavor == URI_LIST_FLAVOR ) {
          return new String( "file:///home/robins/Desktop/swingx-1.0-javadoc.jar" );
        }
        throw new UnsupportedFlavorException( flavor );
      }
    };
    clipBoard.setContents( transferable, null );
    Action pasteAction = TransferHandler.getPasteAction();
    pasteAction.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( testComponent, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Paste" ) );
    assertEquals( transferable.getTransferData( URI_LIST_FLAVOR ), transferHandler.transferable.getTransferData( URI_LIST_FLAVOR ) );
  }

  private static class TestingTransferHandler extends TransferHandler{
    public Transferable transferable;
    @Override
    public boolean canImport( TransferSupport support ) {
      return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean importData( TransferSupport support ) {
      transferable = support.getTransferable();
      try{
        if ( transferable.isDataFlavorSupported( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor ) ) {
          System.out.println("File list flavor");
          List<File> fileList = ( List<File> ) transferable.getTransferData( DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor );
          System.out.println( "fileList = " + fileList );
        }
        if ( transferable.isDataFlavorSupported( URI_LIST_FLAVOR )){
          System.out.println("URI list flavor");
          String uriList = ( String ) transferable.getTransferData( URI_LIST_FLAVOR );
          System.out.println( "uriList = " + uriList );
        }
        return true;
      } catch ( UnsupportedFlavorException e ) {
        return false;
      } catch ( IOException e ) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(  ) );
        contentPane.setTransferHandler( new TestingTransferHandler() );
        frame.setContentPane( contentPane );
        frame.setSize( 200,200 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      }
    } );
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 tough question :-) you probably already checked if/how FEST can handle this? no further idea ...

Comment: Essentially, file transfer is supplied as `List` of `File`s.  You need to be able to create a `Transferable` with the `DataFlavor` of `DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`.  Next, you need to some how inject that into the DnD API...that's where the fun is

Comment: @kleopatra See [Fest Wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Simulating+Drag+%27n+Drop). Sounds like they just fake mouse events (which was my first idea for D&D testing between Swing components, but for me it is sufficient to test the `TransferHandler`), so doesn't seem usable to drag-and-drop files from outside the application

Comment: hmm .. not quite sure that I understand you correctly: assuming you want to test that your TransferHandler can handle _imports_ from whereever, @MadProgrammer 's approach should help. Fill the clipboard with a file list and trigger the paste action of the transferHandler to test.

Comment: @kleopatra I meant there is no need to test the full Swing drag-and-drop mechanism, I just need to make sure my drag-and-drop related code is working as intended (which comes down to testing my `TransferHandler` with the same input as when the user would perform a drag-and-drop with the mouse)

Comment: So, you need to create a DropTargetDropEvent & pass it in via the DropTarget with the Transferable properly populated with the correct DataFlavor

Comment: @MadProgrammer I updated the question with some more code, and some more text. I hope it is more clear now why the current approach is not really suited for my needs

Comment: scratching head: _it is silly to test this with a hard-coded Transferable_ - don't get it: as long as that hard-coded object mocks a "real" one, your test should be fine. Probably overlooking something?

Comment: @kleopatra It is that the hard-coded one will only catch the subtle differences between different OS/JVM, network drive vs local file, ... if I go over all those combinations and include them in the test (by providing a hardcoded transferable for each). If I can reuse the `Transferable` creation, I just need to write the test and run it on all those combinations. See for example that on my Linux machine I receive a `Tranferable` which does not contain any data for the filelist flavor which is different then on Windows if I recall correctly

Comment: ahh ... I see. Thanks for your patience in explaining :-)

Comment: After reading your update, what you want to achieve, I don't think is possible, as the transferable is generated by translating the OS's event by the JVM implementation, unless you happen to to know the exact details of each JVM. I'm also curious about the different data flavours your receiving, in the experience (Mac & Windows) I also receive a filelist flavour.

Comment: @MadProgrammer As said on my Linux machine I get the URI flavor and not the filelist, while on my Mac it is the filelist and not the URI. Never receive them both, although in my linked question I had a case where I received them both when drag-and-dropping an URL on the application.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it was Linux, I read Windows :P

Answer (score 1):

Unit-testing Swing GUI is always painful, let alone D&D. However, I believe it can be done.

There are two things to notice:

1. Currently, you're not testing D&D at all, but rather copy-paste. This is also a form of data transfer, but the use of `copyAction` and `pasteAction` causes you to really not go through any of the steps of D&D
2. You mention that you want to check the part that receives the file, and therefore you created a custom Transferable, but I would like to argue that you're trying to test the wrong thing. The part that handles the data can be implemented as a package private method handling a `Transferable` containing the data, and tested with a simple unit test (no Swing components involved)

I believe that what you should be testing, if you care about D&D differences between different OS, is that the D&D process itself is working, i.e.:

1. The component with the data (the `DragSource`) is requested to provide the data, and that it provides it
2. The component requesting the data (the `DropTarget`) receives the data and handles it
3. Optionally, you might want to check that different conditions are allowed or disallowed (e.g. copy vs. move, etc.)

You can test this by either using `FEST`'s `ComponentDragAndDrop` class (see [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/FEST/Simulating+Drag+%27n+Drop)).

If you want to write you own implementation (why would you want to do that ?!) you could:
Replace both the source and target components' `TransferHandler`s with mocks (or spies to be more accurate), that on top of calling the real methods, would enable you to verify that the expected methods are called with the expected data

Comment: Note that I do not create the Transferable. It is about drag-and-dropping files (local and network) onto my application

Answer (score 0):

if you are not limited to unit testing, you can try to write an GUI test. There are several frameworks for Swing, see this thread - [Unit testing framework for a Swing UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575837/unit-testing-framework-for-a-swing-ui)

I have been using jemmy for a while several years back and it was ok, if the test was simple

Comment: Problem is that I need to test a drag of something from outside my application. I looked at FEST and it only provides support for drag-and-drop in the same Swing application

Comment: aha, sorry, I haven't caught that. In this case my input is meaningless. Quite interesting topic by the way, if you will find that it is possible, please post it here

Answer (score 0):

Maybe AutoIt Script could help:[See here](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

You can create a windows script to simulate the necessary mouse or key events. Then run this script from within you test and see what would happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As said in the comments on the question, I need to test Windows/Linux and even Solaris. So a Windows scripting tool is not sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. It's pretty cool for testing human interaction. I don't know if you can drag and drop files.. but it makes sense that you can!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Swinput](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/swinput/) to simulate input events on Linux.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use mocks. I'm using  [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) framework.

Comment: And how will a mock help me in testing the specific drag-and-drop differences between different OS ?