# Java - How to drag and drop a file on to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, file, drag-and-drop, jtextarea

i have a JTextField inside a JFrame, and I want it to find the file path of a file whenever the file is dragged in to the JTextField. Should I use some kind of Listener? How should I do this?

```
public class UI extends JFrame{
    String s;
    JTextArea textfield = new JTextArea();
    public UI(){
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(1000,800);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Cloavy Compiler");
        textfield.setSize(1000,800);
        add(textfield);

    }
        public void onDrag(){
      s = filepath;
     }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find answers in the [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.

Comment: can you enter an example please?

Comment: @Ewen: Did you visit the link that Andrew posted? It has got some great examples as well!

Comment: Show us your best attempt with the example that is closest to what is required.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700073/drag-and-drop-differences-between-jdk1-6-and-jdk1-7) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771918/testing-drag-and-drop-files-onto-application). In both question I have included an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for drag-and-drop which retrieve the URI and the files from the `Transferable`